# Database error while submitting the form in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem in CodeIgniter. Previously when I have submitted a form which was uploaded in the server it run properly. But now I uploaded the same form in the server and while running it is giving 1048 error number.

The same form is running fine in the local host. But error is coming when I uploading the same in Server saying fields are NULL. But code is ok.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Compare the versions of MySQL being used locally and on the server. The error clearly says 'NULL values' are being inserted. Print your Query to check if all values are going correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be miss configuration or MySQLi version issue. In latest version it asks to define default value of each column.

It can be handled, if you have WHMCS access.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you attach a screenshot for the same

Comment: When I echo the same there is no echo coming

Comment: It would be more helpful if you share more detail with us.  Need to know what exactly your facing.

Attaching screenshot or sample of code would help better to understanding this issue.

Comment: Go through the link

Comment: @AvijitPaul Problem is in code. Where you are getting values, it does not being passed to your model. May I see your code please?

Comment: @AvijitPaul Are you getting values when you are printing $this->input->post(); at the beginning of your controller method?

Comment: No . That is what I am worried

Comment: Locally the same thing its working fine.But the same is not working in Server

Comment: @AvijitPaul Try to compare phpinfo on both local and live server.

It would be easy if I can see your view and controller file.

Comment: thanks but I have solved my problem by changing the .htaccess file setting

Comment: @AvijitPaul Please share it with us too so we know what was the exact issue.
Thanks